# Laravel 6, Vue.js component not updating

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm, components

So the standard example-component that is included with Laravel works just fine.

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

ExampleComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>TEXT</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
                <div class="card-body" id="app">
                    <example-component></example-component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                </a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                            Mayer
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And im still only seeing the stuff from the example-component that ships with laravel.

(https://prnt.sc/r5cbtr)

But when I make a change to the ExampleComponent like adding a h2-tag or something the blade doesn't update and the change wont come through.

I also ran npm run watch, still no change.

Hope someone can help.

Edit:

Comment: Where you load the app.js file? And where you create the new Vue instance?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ in layouts/app.blade.php <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>, when i remove this even the example-component doesn't work anymore.

Comment: So you can see the component on your browser but can not see the changes and you have running `npm run watch`? Make sure you doesn't have another `<div id="app">` in the layout blade too. I can't see anything wrong in your code, but would be usefull if you share the entirely app.js and the layout.blade because maybe the issue is in another place

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I added the app.blade.php, the whole app.js and you can see that I made some changes to the ExampleComponent.vue but I still only get stuff that you can see in the screenshot down below.

Comment: Well, I can't see anythig wrong, you dom't see any errors/warnings in your browser console? Just for test,,, In your `app.js`, try with this: 
`require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent'
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { ExampleComponent },
});`. And in `app.blade.php` move the script load to the last line of the body and use `mix()` instead `asset()`:
`<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>`. Then run `npm run production` in the console and reload the page in your browser.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I found the error myself now, I had to disable cache in google chrome, now its working

Comment: Anyway, I recommend using `mix()` instead of `asset()`, which avoids those cache problems when you run `npm run production`. And if you don't want to disable the browser cache, you can reload the page with `Ctrl` + `F5` and chrome will reload the page ignoring the cache.